# 'failed to produce diagnostic for expression' error on var body: some View in SwiftUI Xcode 13.2

Tags: swift, xcode, error-handling, swiftui, xcode13

I'm a new user of SwiftUI and Xcode 13.2. I'm taking a course on Udemy, but hit a roadblock when there was an error that said "Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project". It was on the line that said  `var body: some View {}`. This is the entire code.

```html
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var userText:String = ""
    @State var mode:Int = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if mode == 1 {
                Text(userText.capitalized())
                    .font(.largeTitle)
            } else if mode == 2 {
                Text(userText.lowercased())
                    .font(.largeTitle)
            } else {
                Text(userText.uppercased())
                    .font(.largeTitle)
            }
        }
        TextField("Enter text here...", text: $userText)
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .padding()
        Text(userText)
            .font(.largeTitle)
        HStack{
            Button(action: {mode = 1}) {
                RoundedButton(text: "Capitalize", color: .green)
                    .padding(5)
            }
            Button(action: {mode = 2}) {
                RoundedButton(text: "Lower", color: .blue)
            }
            Button(action: {mode = 3}) {
                RoundedButton(text: "All Caps", color: .red)
                    .padding(5)
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct RoundedButton: View {
    var text:String
    var color:Color
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .bold()
            .frame(maxWidth:.infinity)
            .padding()
            .background(color)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .cornerRadius(10)
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .previewInterfaceOrientation(.portrait)
    }
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Comment out line by line, it is usually a typo.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has to do with the condition found in your first `if` condition.

```
Text(userText.capitalized())
```

SwiftUI does not like the use of `.capitalized()`

In your third condition, you are using `.uppercased()`. Maybe that is what you meant to use instead?

To answer the question, the fix for the issue would be to remove the `.capitalized()`

Answer (score 0):

the function `capitalized()` is a function that does not exist in swift.
There is however a `capitalized(with locale: Locale?)` see this doc
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1414023-capitalized
for explanation.

To capitalized a string you can use the method `capitalized`, such as `theString.capitalized`. Without the ending `()`.

So the error you get is due to using a nonexistent function. Replace  `capitalized()` with `capitalized` and that will fix your error.

In your code use the following to fix your error and capitalize your string in the Text:

```
 Text(userText.capitalized)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.